# Does a musician under an LLC have to file a foreign qualification for shows in other states?

Tags: small-business, limited-liability-company

Does a musical band or similar service under an LLC have to file for a foreign qualification in every state they play a show in/employ their service?

Comment: What country?  (The US, for example, doesn't have the concept of intra-state "foreign qualification".)

Comment: Good question, this seems tricky! On the one hand, many states would tend to require it as you are offering services and/or selling products in that state (like merchandise after the show, presumably). On the other hand, many states don't require it when business is considered temporary or short-term (say, under 30 days).

Comment: @RonJohn The country tag would be good for clarification, but foreign qualification is a US concept: https://www.delawareinc.com/blog/what-is-foreign-qualification/ or: https://ct.wolterskluwer.com/resource-center/guides/expanding-business-other-states-domestic-yet-foreign-qualification "Domestic" meaning in-state, and "foreign" meaning "from outside of that state" in corporate law parlance. Corporate law is a mess, and a great generator of demand for lawyers - which I'm sure is a coincidence :)

Comment: @BrianH does that have anything to do with a band from Texas playing a gig in North Dakota (where presumably the concert promoter would handle taxes, etc)?  It's not like the Texas band is opening a bank account in ND or registering as a DE corporation...

Comment: @RonJohn That's what makes it a mess. Every state defines "transacting business" or "conducting affairs" in their own way, it appears. Most I've seen have an exemption where single transactions that last less than 30 days don't count (Michigan, for instance) - so a single gig in a state would be fine. But then some say explicitly that this must be "non-recurring" - so how long between gigs is "non-recurring"? How many times? If you play in Houston in January, play shows elsewhere, then come back to play in Austin in August, is that recurring? Beats me!

Comment: Oh, and here's a fun example from Michigan: https://www.michigan.gov/lara/0,4601,7-154-89334_61343_35413_35426-120069--,00.html The state government says: "...foreign corporation whether profit or nonprofit, is required to obtain a Certificate of Authority if it is "transacting business" or "conducting affairs" in this state. These terms are technical and decisions to apply for a certificate of authority should be based on proposed activities in this state, the statute, and applicable court decisions." That does not inspire confidence.

Comment: @BrianH is this (another reason why) bands work through concert promoters (who handle all this for them)?

Comment: @RonJohn I'm afraid that is where my experience reaches zero - the organization and workings of the business side of music and art remain mostly a mystery to me. Many work on a cash basis to avoid all this, some work with existing corporate entities, some get paid as a contractor and thus have no corporate reporting (but state taxes, yuck), etc. Its very common at this level of organizational complexity to just say "you'll need to ask a lawyer/CPA" because it is not designed to be easy, incorporation can make things harder, and many people just ignore the law and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

Being a musician isn't that different from other businesses in this respect.  A company has to register or qualify in a state if it is "doing business" in the state.

Whether a company is doing business in a state is a very blurry line.  If you have an office or employees working in a state then you are definitely doing business, but occasional visits to a state for business reasons would generally not rise to doing business. See [this article](https://ct.wolterskluwer.com/resource-center/articles/foreign-qualification-what-constitutes-doing-business-in-another-state) for more details.

If you go on tour to a bunch of states, then I expect you are not doing business in those states and don't need to qualify.  If you have a weekly gig in another state that is close to your home, then you probably are doing business there and should qualify.

If you are somewhere in between and are not sure, then you can probably get away with not qualifying, especially if your revenue is small.  It is not uncommon for small companies to neglect to register in other states, and it is hard for states to enforce this especially since the "doing business" requirements are very vague.

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking a barber if you need a haircut. The state will always say yes.

The consequences for not registering are often times non-existent even if the state notices. Some states even have retroactive limited liability if you need to register a business just to use their courts.

This is worth ignoring.

This changes if there are revenue/income tax obligations though.